# I don't understand this iOS stack trace from BugSense/Mint... where is my code actually crashing at?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, crash

My app here is named `Movies`. I am using Splunk Mint (formerly BugSense) to capture crash reports. I recently updated to their new 4.0 SDK. Here is a crash report today that I don't understand. At what line exactly is the crash happening in my code?

Crash is: `NSInvalidArgumentException *** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument`

You would think line #4? But I have no idea what the heck `URLBlackListManager` is. Or is it line #0, a crash inside of `MKSKProduct` (the code I've been using for years to make in-app purchases easy), but then why would it say it's coming from `CoreFoundation`? Or is it line #10, the last line that `Movies` actually gets called with my code?

And I have NO clue what `SplunkNSURLConnectionSendSynchronousRequestReturningResponseError` is and their website doesn't have any info on it.

I have been unable to report the crash, but it's happened at least 10 times on different devices for different people.

I'm a bit confused... anyone have any ideas?

```
0   CoreFoundation  -[MKSKProduct verifyReceiptOnComplete:onError:] (in Movies) (MKSKProduct.m:196) + 868307    
1   libobjc.A.dylib _mh_execute_header (in Movies) + 15567  
2   CoreFoundation  -[MKSKProduct verifyReceiptOnComplete:onError:] (in Movies) (MKSKProduct.m:190) + 868117    
3   Foundation  -[CollectionViewController collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:] (in Movies) (CollectionViewController.m:227) + 154361  
4   Movies  -[URLBlackListManager containsURL:] (in Movies) + 129   
5   Movies  SplunkNSURLConnectionSendSynchronousRequestReturningResponseError (in Movies) + 453 
6   Foundation  -[SettingsViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] (in Movies) (SettingsViewController.m:278) + 292459    
7   Foundation  -[SettingsViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] (in Movies) (SettingsViewController.m:270) + 292251    
8   Foundation  +[MKSKProduct connection:didFailWithError:] (in Movies) (MKSKProduct.m:299) 
9   Movies  -[iPhoneRSS initWithURL:andItemName:] (in Movies) (iPhoneRSS.m:39) + 871897 
10  Movies  -[CreateUsernameViewController submit:] (in Movies) (CreateUsernameViewController.m:123) + 572531   
11  UIKit   -[ImportViewController setUrlTextField:] (in Movies) (ImportViewController.m:34) + 262231   
12  UIKit   -[ImportViewController setInstructionsLabel:] (in Movies) (ImportViewController.m:32) + 262135  
13  UIKit   -[ImportViewController instructionsLabel] (in Movies) (ImportViewController.m:32) + 262097  
14  UIKit   __43-[CollectorsAdViewController openAppStore:]_block_invoke (in Movies) (CollectorsAdViewController.m:279) + 177975    
15  UIKit   -[ImportViewController ebaySearchWithCountry:andBarcode:] (in Movies) (ImportViewController.m:2464) + 260687    
16  UIKit   -[ImportViewController ebaySearchWithCountry:andBarcode:] (in Movies) (ImportViewController.m:2427) + 259873    
17  UIKit   -[ImportViewController importCollectorzData:] (in Movies) (ImportViewController.m:1488) + 239339    
18  UIKit   -[WishlistViewController tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:] (in Movies) (WishlistViewController.m:1187) + 63725   
19  UIKit   -[WishlistViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] (in Movies) (WishlistViewController.m:929) + 57239   
20  CoreFoundation  -[MainViewController optionsTouched:] (in Movies) (MainViewController.m:687) + 651867   
21  CoreFoundation  -[MainViewController startActivityIndicator] (in Movies) (CGGeometry.h:294) + 649003    
22  CoreFoundation  -[MainViewController loadUp] (in Movies) (MainViewController.m:405) + 642847    
23  CoreFoundation  -[WishlistViewController themeSetup] (in Movies) (WishlistViewController.m:224) + 32527 
24  CoreFoundation  -[WishlistViewController loadDataOffline] (in Movies) (WishlistViewController.m:214) + 31987    
25  GraphicsServices    -[WishlistViewController loadUp] (in Movies) (WishlistViewController.m:412) + 38499 
26  UIKit   -[EditImageViewController viewWillAppear:] (in Movies) (EditImageViewController.m:102) + 450925 
27  Movies  main (in Movies) (main.m:16) + 891191   
28  libdyld.dylib   _mh_execute_header (in Movies) + 6839
```

Here's the `verifyReceiptOnComplete` code by the way from line #0 in the stack trace... let me know if you see any possible way to get a nil NSString crash anywhere here:

```
- (void) verifyReceiptOnComplete:(void (^)(void)) completionBlock
                         onError:(void (^)(NSError*)) errorBlock
{
  self.onReceiptVerificationSucceeded = completionBlock;
  self.onReceiptVerificationFailed = errorBlock;

  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", OWN_SERVER, @"verifyProduct.php"]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url 
                                                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData 
                                                        timeoutInterval:60];

    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];     
    [theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSString *receiptDataString = [self.receipt base64EncodedString];

    NSString *postData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"receiptdata=%@", receiptDataString];

    NSString *length = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];    
    [theRequest setValue:length forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];  

    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

  self.theConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];    
  [self.theConnection start];   
}
```

Comment: what happens in collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath: in your CollectionViewController?

Comment: enable breakpoints and it will tell you with green highlight where the crash happens

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash log. Then you will see the exact line causing the problem.

Comment: @Kreiri - I should have looked harder at that line... that may be it. I am setting an NSString there. I will see if I can dig deeper and provide more info.

Comment: @rmaddy - The problem is that these are not downloadable crash dumps (like from iTunes Connect). They can only provide what I'm showing you above. It's already been symbolicated in there system by me uploading the dSYMs folder to them, and they spit out what I've shown you.

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled upon this bug myself and here is what I found:

If you use Cocoapods to install Splunk Mint Express, you get two different Pods:

```
$> pod search Splunk

-> SplunkMint (4.0.4)
   Usage, performance and crash monitoring for your iOS apps
   pod 'SplunkMint', '~> 4.0.4'
   - Homepage: https://mint.splunk.com/
   - Source:   download.splunk.com/misc/mint/SplunkMint-iOS.framework.zip
   - Versions: 4.0.4, 4.0.3, 4.0.2, 4.0.1 [master repo]


-> SplunkMint-iOS (4.0.21)
   Usage, performance and crash monitoring for your iOS apps
   pod 'SplunkMint-iOS', '~> 4.0.21'
   - Homepage: https://mint.splunk.com/
   - Source:   download.splunk.com/misc/mint/SplunkMint-iOS.framework.4.0.21.zip
   - Versions: 4.0.21, 4.0.17, 4.0.1 [master repo]
```

When I was using `SplunkMint` I had the same crash but switching to `SplunkMint-iOS` fixed it. I don't know what the differences are between the two Pods (I didn't even have to change my code initializing `Mint`) but I filed a bug to Splunk to let them know about it.

I will edit my post if I find something else,

Hope this will help,

Answer (score 0):

Update: Splunk Mint (formerly BugSense) is investigating. They said there may be a bug and that is why you can see `SplunkNSURLConnectionSendSynchronousRequestReturningResponseError` and `URLBlackListManager` in there. I'll edit in what they ultimately have to say.